# String literal token generates MismatchedTokenException with escape sequence token

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am currently trying to implement an Antlr parser.
I obtain strange MismatchedTokenException in a token that identifies string literals once I add escape sequence support.

Following is the Antlr parser example that causes the issue:

```
rule: STRING_LITERAL ;

STRING_LITERAL
  :
  '"' STRING_GUTS '"'
  ;

fragment
STRING_GUTS
  :
  ( ESC | ~('\\' | '"') )*
  ;

ESC
  :
  '\\'
  ( '\\' | '"' )
  ;
```

Do you seen any issue in this code?

Note that if I remove ESC from the STRING_GUTS, the string parsing is working well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to post the input you're getting this error with, the ANTLR version you're using, and the way you're running your test(s), because I see no problem with that grammar, as you can see:

#### T.g

```java
grammar T;

rule
  :  STRING_LITERAL {System.out.println("parsed : " + $STRING_LITERAL.text);}
  ;

STRING_LITERAL 
  :  '"' STRING_GUTS '"'
  ;

fragment
STRING_GUTS
  :  (ESC | ~('\\' | '"'))*
  ;

// also a fragment rule perhaps?
ESC
  :  '\\' ('\\' | '"')
  ;
```

#### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = "\"a\\\"b\\\\c\"";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    System.out.println("src    : " + src);
    parser.rule();
  }
}
```

If I generate a lexer and parser from you grammar (1), compile all java-source files (2) and run the Main class (3):

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g    # 1
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java               # 2
java -cp .;antlr-3.3.jar Main                # 3
```

The following is printed to the console:

```
src    : "a\"b\\c"
parsed : "a\"b\\c"
```

I.e.: the input `src` is parsed as expected.

If you're encountering problems with ANTLRWorks' interpreter: don't use it, it's a bit buggy. Either use ANTLRWorks' debugger, or use a custom class as I did above.

Comment: You were right, I tested using the antlrworks debugger and it's parsing well. Any idea why the same code is not working through interpreters of either antlrworks or antlr IDE Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: @greydet, ANTLRWorks' interpreter is simply buggy. And Eclipse's plugin uses ANTLRWorks' interpreter, AFAIK.

Comment: Is there any other tool "less buggy" to help in antlr parser creation? Thanks for the help

Comment: ANTLRWorks' debugger works great (but I already mentioned it in my answer). And you're welcome.

Comment: So if we go the antlrworks debugger way, is it possible to use it without generating & compiling the resulting code? In fact what is the best practice in the parser design to keep it independant of custom code that handles the parsing result?

Comment: _So if we go the antlrworks debugger way, is it possible to use it without generating & compiling the resulting code?_, the debugger must generate the lexer/parser in able to debug input.

Comment: _what is the best practice in the parser design to keep it independant of custom code that handles the parsing result?_, are you talking about debugging, or (unit) testing?